# how to set eight uilabel in one uitableviewcell with same width using auto layout

Tags: swift, uitableview, uilabel, ios-autolayout

After searching and applying many result I have no desired solution for my problem.

How can I Set label so I can display all label with same font size in tableview cell.

I need to display 5 label and 2 button in one tableview cell in Horizontal.

[image]

Pls help me how can I set all label .

Comment: Use stackview horizontal and have each element to equal width with the first element

Comment: Not sure what is your question exactly ? . Did you set all the font size same in the storyboard or the code you are using ? Or please add more details to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow my steps.

**Step1 :**

Add 5 label and 2 button in storyboard tableViewCell.

**Step2**:

select all `label` with button then embedded in `stackview`

[image]

**Step3:**

Select the `stackView` and add `autolayout`. `Leading` 0 and `trailing` 0.

[image]

**step4:**

Select the `attribute inspector` and set the `alignment` and `distribution` like the picture.

[image]

Set the `font`.

It may helps you. Thank you.